# How can I override some properties in nested interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I need override some properties in nested interface. I try it:

```
public interface INode {
    INode Parent { get; }
    ICollection<INode> Items { get; }
    Boolean IsKey { get; }
    String Name { get; set; }
    Object Value { get; set; }
    Boolean IsValidValue(Object value);
    Boolean HasFixedValues { get; }
    ICollection<Object> FixedValues { get; }
    String Description { get; set; }
    String GetFullPath();
    Boolean IsExists();
    INode GetFromXML(XElement xml);
    XElement WriteToXml();
}

public interface INode<T> : INode {       
    new T Value { get; set; }
    new Boolean IsValidValue(T value);
    new ICollection<T> FixedValues { get; }
}
```

But I get compilation error. How can I do it?

Exception messages:

> Error 21  Method 'set_Value' in type
>   'AndreyBushman.AutoCAD.INode_Impl`1' from assembly 'AcadInfo_Accessor,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have
>   an implementation.    TestProject Error   22  The "BuildShadowTask" task
>   failed unexpectedly. System.TypeLoadException: Method 'set_Value' in
>   type 'AndreyBushman.AutoCAD.INode_Impl`1' from assembly
>   'AcadInfo_Accessor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Comment: Could you show these interfaces' implementation code. The problem is not in the interfaces' declarations.

Comment: I still didn't write implementation. Only these interfaces.

Comment: If I commenting the `INode<T>` interface, then exception is not occur. (I use MS Visual Studio 2012 & C# 3.5)

Comment: Where does this `INode_Impl` type come from ?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing this interface, make sure you implement both the member from `INode` and the one from `INode<T>`:

```
class Test : INode<int>
{
    public int Value {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    object INode.Value {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```